# Android wallpaper/background dimensions

Tags: android, background, wallpaper

Which are the default dimension of the Home wallpaper/background for the various Android screen configurations (small, normal and large screens with low, medium and high density)?

Are 9-patch PNG files supported for the wallpaper? Should I be using these instead?

I found a method in API level 5 that gives you the minimum size of the wallpaper, but I would like to support previous versions of Android as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A wallpaper is twice as wide as the device held in portrait mode. So 960x800 on a Nexus One, 960x854 on a Droid, 640x480 on a G1/Magic/Hero, etc.

Comment: Thanks Romain! Nice to see Google's Android developers here.

Comment: Is this still true for the newer UI's?

Comment: Is this also true for tablet UI's?

Comment: @Romain Guy: Any chance you can comment on this?

Answer (score 3):

[This article on the Android Developers' site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) shows the range of screen resolutions for each density.

I believe the wallpapers have to match the screen resolution and are not stretched.  You can see this if, for example, you create a new emulator with a high screen density like 480x854.  The default home screen background is centred, with large black bands at the top and bottom.

The [`WallpaperManager` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setResource%28int%29) indicates that you must use a PNG- or JPEG-format image, even if you use the `setResource()` method — the resource *must* be a `Bitmap` and so not a nine-patch or other type of `Drawable`.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. However, at least the backgrounds that come with the device are larger than the screen resolution. This allows the background to move when you swipe left or right on the home screen and change the page.

I believe the height matches the screen resolution, but not the width, which is equal or larger to the biggest dimension, as the background moves both in portrait and landscape mode.

Comment: Oops, quite right.. I was going to say that you need to have a background with at least the biggest dimension squared. I have an HTC Hero which doesn't do landscape on the home screen, so I haven't really investigated how the swipe/width issue is handled.

Answer (score 0):

Don't guess, ask the WallpaperManager:

```
  manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
  width = manager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
  height = manager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();
```