# Android wallpaper got stretched

Tags: android, wallpaper

My screen size is `600px * 800px`.
I created some wallpapers whose sizes are `600px * 800px` or `width:height=3:4`,
when they were set as wallpaper, they got stretched, so the lower and right part couldn't be seen.

Does anybody how to solve this problem to make my wallpapers fit to the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android crops a part of your wallpaper so that when you swipe left and right, the background scrolls with it. For more information see [this link](http://androidforums.com/android-media/131266-android-not-wallpaper-friendly.html)  or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010399/android-wallpaper-background-dimensions)