# Android setting wallpaper gone wrong

Tags: java, android, bitmap, resize, wallpaper

So I was developing wallpaper changer long time ago and got it released. After a while I started receiving comment the wallpaper not resizing correctly. Also I tried on different sizes of emus and they were right. I scale the bitmap correctly etc. but somehow android tends to rescale the wallpaper even bigger! Is there way to avoid that? 
My code:

```
Display display = parent.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
                    int width = display.getWidth();
                    int height = display.getHeight();
                    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(wallpaper, width, height, true);
                WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getContext());
                wm.setBitmap(scaled);
```

I've been trying other ways too but nothing seems help, even if I afterwards check if the rescaled wallpaper is right size etc. :(
Any ideas?

Comment: I remember reading something about the wallpaper manager trying to resize images automatically a while back...You might want to look around for articles about that.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010399/android-wallpaper-background-dimensions for info on the proper dimensions for wallpaper.

Comment: I've got proper site but as Max stated " wallpaper manager trying to resize images automatically" And the question is, can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could resize the wallpapers using the size specified by [WallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getDesiredMinimumWidth%28%29) and [WallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getDesiredMinimumHeight%28%29), instead of the display size. That way, even the requirements set by custom home applications (like those possibly set by device manufacturers and/or service providers) will be respected, meaning a (much) larger compatibility for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after resize wallpaper had the same size, but diffrent resolution.

In my case that code solved problem:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap
                .createScaledBitmap(whatever, width, height, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to create overlay image.

1. Create a blank image with size of `WallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth()` x `WallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight()`
2. Resize your bitmap to screen size with, `Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();` `bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), false);`
3. Overlay your wallpaper on center of blank image. And set Overlay as wallpaper.