# Wallpaper Android Sizes

Tags: android

I need develop app to set an wallpaper. 
What are the specification of wallpapers for Android? Sizes, mdpi, and ldpi hdpi?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android wallpaper/background dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010399/android-wallpaper-background-dimensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a long list of Android Devices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices 
In the "Display" column you have sizes and resolutions of presumably all of Android Devices. You maybe want to do statistical summary?

Answer (score 2):

They are actually ranges of pixel densities. Check out: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

They give approximate averages on that page of:

ldpi:  ~120dpi

mdpi:  ~160dpi

hdpi:  ~240dpi

xhdpi: ~320dpi

nodpi: density independent

tvdpi: ~213dpi (mostly for TVs, apps shouldn't need it)

**EDIT**
This may be useful as well.

> To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you
>   should follow the *3:4:6:8 scaling ratio* between the four generalized
>   densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48
>   pixels for medium-density screen (the size for a launcher icon), all
>   the different sizes should be:
>
> 36x36 for low-density
>
> 48x48 for medium-density
>
> 72x72 for high-density
>
> 96x96 for extra high-density

***Also***

> To help you target some of your designs for different types of
>   devices, here are some numbers for typical screen widths:
>
> 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800
>   hdpi, etc).
>
> 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
>
> 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
>
> 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Answer (score 1):

As you design your wall paper for different screen sizes, you'll discover that each design requires a minimum amount of space. So, each generalized screen size above has an associated minimum resolution that's defined by the system. These minimum sizes are in "dp" units—the same units you should use when defining your layouts—which allows the system to avoid worrying about changes in screen density.

- xlarge screens wall paper are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens wall paper are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens wall paper are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens wall paper are at least 426dp x 320dp